# How to open my wishlist top link in new window?

Tags: magento-1.9, wishlist, items

I wants to open my wishlist  top link in new window excluding my account left nevigation menu. and after open this list also display grand total of all wishlist item. finally export it as a pdf formate. anybody knows answer so please help me.....

Comment: add target blank to your wish list code

Comment: i am not able to find wishlist top link file path or exact div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1) To customise wish list from Top links (open it in a new window):

The best way is to do it via **xml**.

Go to `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/layout/local.xml` then add this code **before** `</default>`

```
<reference name="top.links">
    <remove name="wishlist_link"/>
    <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
        <label>My wishlist</label>
        <url>wishlist</url>
        <title>Wishlist</title>
        <prepare>false</prepare>
        <urlParams/>
        <position>1</position>
        <liParams />
        <aParams><![CDATA[target="_blank"]]></aParams>
    </action>
</reference>
```

#### 2) To remove left nav only in wishlist page:

`app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/layout/local.xml` **after** `</default>` :

```
<wishlist_index_index>
    <remove name="left"/>
</wishlist_index_index>
```

#### 3) To remove wish link only in customer dashboard:

Go to : `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/customer/account/navigation.phtml`then add this: `<?php unset($_links['wishlist']); ?>` just after : `<?php $_count = count($_links); ?>`

Save and clear your Magento cache.

Comment: please specify complete path of file. i am not getting file path

Comment: Look my update again please

Comment: i tried this code header link still opening in same location

Comment: yes it open in new window but not showing wishlist count or not excluding my account left  nevigation menu

Comment: you want to remove it also from a left navigation ?

Comment: but i need it in my account page.

Comment: if i remove all menu it from nevigation.phtml then it will not display in my account page also

Comment: yes  i wants to remove left nevigation menu from only wishlist page and also remove wishlist link from my account dashboard left nevigation

Comment: I can't help you if you ask 3 questions in one question ! Be  explicite, tel me all what you want explicitelly, 1) ... 2)... etc...

Comment: 1. i want to open my wishlist link in new window which placed in header (its working now after your help)

Comment: 2. it will be show without left navigation menus of my account. i.e only wishlist item exist in that page.

Comment: 3. finally i wants to export(download) it as a pdf formate

Comment: Look`my update now, for PDF, please open this question in a new post, It requires a new module.

Comment: If it works for you, please validate the answer.

Comment: 2.To remove left nav only in wishlist page: is not working others two solutions are working

Comment: i have try <wishlist_index_index>
    <remove name="left"/>
</wishlist_index_index> this code but still showing left navigation menu on wishlist list item page

Comment: Accept this answer first then i will answer you in the other post that you just published. i tested it and it works

Comment: your answer is accepted

Comment: see here wishlist pdf export question and please help me https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/184048/how-to-export-wishlist-list-item-as-a-pdf-in-magento

Comment: I replied to the other question `wishlist`, question of PDF I have no idea. sorry

Comment: do you know How to get grand total of all wishlist item list?